# Show last line in a TLabel

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a TLabel with fixed height and word wrap. The problem is that when the caption text exceeds the label's height, I can't see the last lines of text. I search entire internet for label components that can scroll down and show the last lines of text that exceeds the height of caption.

As you can see in this picture, line 7 is half visible and line 8 is not even shown:

[image]

I want line 1 to disappear or go up and line 8 be fully visible.

Comment: Use a read only memo and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Set `Label.AutoSize := True;`

Comment: @sami He doesn't want too, then it will be too large.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, I got it, he want to use scrollbars.

Comment: You don't say that you _don't want to use other component_, so you can simply use a `ScrollBox`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `ScrollBox ` will work perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override TLabel's `DoDrawText` virtual method. something like this (example using interposer class):

```
TLabel = class(StdCtrls.TLabel)
protected
  procedure DoDrawText(var Rect: TRect; Flags: Longint); override;
end;

... 

procedure TLabel.DoDrawText(var Rect: TRect; Flags: Longint);
var
  R: TRect;      
  TextHeight: Integer;
begin
  if (Flags and DT_CALCRECT = 0) then
  begin
    R := ClientRect;
    Canvas.Font := Font;
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Text), -1, R, DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_CALCRECT or DT_WORDBREAK);        
    TextHeight := R.Bottom - R.Top;    
    if TextHeight > ClientHeight then
      Rect.Top := Rect.Top - (TextHeight - ClientHeight);
  end;
  inherited DoDrawText(Rect, Flags);
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TScrollBox` :

- Drop a `TScrollBox`.
- Drop a `TLabel` inside the `TScrollBox`.
- Set Label Align to `alTop`.

[image]

Comment: At least leave a comment to say what's wrong with the A.

Comment: Don't see any evidence that scroll bars are desired

Comment: **[_Use a read only memo and scroll to the bottom_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273213/show-last-line-in-a-tlabel/46275458#comment79508928_46273213)**, yes scroll bars are desired, don't be _contradictory_ , you already say _scroll_ .

Comment: Scroll bars can be hidden on a memo

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hidden or not, he don't ask how to hide them, OP want just to scroll and show all the lines in the label. that's it.

Comment: Nope. He wants to show just the bottom lines. He did accept an answer.